ERRORS INSTALLING PAMAC-ALL/PAMAC-FULL , conflicting libpamac-aur with libpamac-full
after fully uninstalling the pamac-aur from the system using the command :
I am using garuda linux

sudo pacman -Rcns pamac-aur

and trying installing the pamac-all or pamac-full.
I get stupid conflicting errors that implicitly reinstall the libpamac-aur after successfully uninstalling it!
pamac-all/pamac-full both depends on libpamac-full and libpamac-aur both at the same time,
but the paradox was:
is that the libpamac-full and libpamac-aur must not be installed on the same machine at the same time!!!!
more details :
> :: Inner conflicts found: libpamac-aur: libpamac-full (libpamac-aur) 
> libpamac-full (libpamac) libpamac-full: libpamac-aur (libpamac)
> pamac-all: pamac-aur (pamac) pamac-aur: pamac-all (pamac)  pamac-all
> (pamac-aur) :: Conflicting packages will have to be confirmed manually

> :: marked out of date: pamac-all Repo (6)
> archlinux-appstream-data-20240526-1  vte-common-0.76.3-1 
> vte3-0.76.3-1  appstream-glib-0.8.3-1 libpamac-aur-11.6.4-1 
> pamac-aur-11.7.1-4 Aur (2) libpamac-full-1:11.6.4-1 
> pamac-all-11.7.1-1


**: libpamac-full-1:11.6.4-1 and libpamac-aur-11.6.4-1 are in conflict. Remove libpamac-aur? [y/N] y
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: removing libpamac-aur breaks dependency 'libpamac-aur>=11.6' required by pamac-aur**

